# Egit: configure rebase as default pull strategy for master branch

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

In our new project we've got 10 repositories, each of which have interdependent Eclipse projects.

I plan to establish a default workflow, where each developer is working on the master branch and uses the commit-pull-push cycle. To reduce commits and get a nice linear history I prefer rebase as standard strategy for pull. This works fine, if `branch.master.rebase=true` is set.

Unfortunatelly it has to be set manually for all repositories, after they are cloned with EGit. I tried setting `branch.autosetuprebase=always`, but this affects manually created local branches only, not the master branch after a clone.

I would like to automatize the initial setting of `branch.master.rebase=true` to reduce errors and for convenience. Is there a way to do it? Preferably inside of Eclipse/Egit, but other ideas are welcome, too.

Comment: autosetuprebase should also work for clone. What version of EGit are you using?

Comment: @robinst: It is 1.3.0.201202151440-r

Comment: I feel so silly, Version 2.0.0 respects autosetuprebase when cloning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned by Ozan's response to their original question, the correct solution is to add

```
[branch]
    autosetuprebase=always
```

in `.gitconfig`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make this change in the Eclipse GUI

1. Open the Git Perspective in Eclipse.
2. Expand your repository, Branches, Local.
3. Right-click your branch and click "Configure Branch".
4. Check "Rebase".
5. Click OK. Do for the rest of the branches pushed to origin.

Comment: Does this work properly / reliably? Any experience here?