# "git pull --rebase" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Our version control manager recommends us to use `git pull --rebase` to pull new changes from upstream branch. I want to use EGit (Eclipse plugin for git) to execute that. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673901/egit-configure-rebase-as-default-pull-strategy-for-master-branch

Comment: Maybe yes, but I think my question is more concrete.

Comment: That's why no close-vote :) But always good to have references.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
git config branch.*branch-name*.rebase true
```

And `pull` will automatically rebase.

You can set it up to configure new branches automatically.

```
git config branch.autosetuprebase always
```

Answer (score 48):

You can also change the rebase configuration of a branch from within Eclipse:

1. Open the *Git Repositories* view and navigate to the local branch
2. Open the context menu and select *Configure Branch...*
3. In the resulting dialog, select the *Rebase* checkbox

EGit also honors the "branch.autosetuprebase" configuration when a new branch is created.

Comment: As he mentions he wants to do this specifically in Eclipse (and not from the command prompt), this should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm presuming the accepted answer by @gzm0 will also fix the problem in Eclipse, no?` And it offers a solution that works for all branches.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, it has the same effect (the dialog also sets `branch.$branchname.rebase` to `true`). And EGit also respects the `branch.autosetuprebase` configuration.

Answer (score 4):

New update in Eclipse Mars shows the 'Pull...' option to rebase:
[image: Team -> Pull...]
[image: Popup to select rebase option]