# Eclipse Git - switch branch without merge

Tags: eclipse, git

This is maybe a dumb question, but I could not find a way to solve my problem. I am working with Eclipse and Git. 
When switching and pulling branches to work on different features, the local commits of the previous branch are added to the commit history of the new branch.

Let say I am working on a branch A, commit twice, then I create from master a branch B, switch to this branch B, pull, and perform one commit. Now my branch B contains the changes made on branch A + the commit made on branch B, making it difficult to create a pull request to merge the change of the only commit B to master.
I would like my local commits/changes to be erased when switching to another branch. How can I do that with Eclipse Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with eclipse, I noticed there was two possible pull actions:

- The default one does Fetch + merge, resulting in the mess described in the question
- The other option allow you to select Fetch + rebase, to rebase your working directory to the state of the remote branch.

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17324792/10631518 you can even make rebase the default behaviour by running

```
git config branch.autosetuprebase always
```