# Eclipse: How to push a new commit after editing a readme file?

Tags: eclipse, github

I'm working with eclipse and I push the commits from eclipse.
I have a repo with a few commits.

Few days ago I edited direct in the github account the readme file of this repo.

Now I wanted to push new commit, but the changes does not appear in the repo.

In eclipse/ repo history I can find the commit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do, from Eclipse, a [pull --rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37839529/6309) first, in order to replay your local commits on top of the update remote branch (where you made a commit a few days ago)

[image: pull --rebase in Eclipse]

Then, and only then will you be able to push.